# Speech Recognition in other languages

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, internationalization

I read about speech recognition in .NET Framework (`System.Speech.Recognition` namespace) and I made some application that performs the recognition but all of these application are applicable only for English.

So how could I use the `System.Speech.Recognition` tool to make the recognition of other languages such as French or Arabic.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using English-based framework for recognition. Find desired language-based engine and use it in order to support multilanguage recognition. Unfortunately, artificial intelligence isn't developed still.

Comment: Thanks beryllium I will try to find language-based engine